# How to output functions from plugin inside theme

Tags: plugin-development, functions, shortcode, page-template

I am using a plugin `Chargebee WP Membership` to connect up to their API to process payments. At the moment they are only using shortcodes to restrict content.

What I am trying to do, is output the functions of these shortcodes inside the page template. So far I've attempted the `do_shortcode` method but would rather access the function directly.

Github file: https://github.com/brendenplugin/chargebee-wp-membership-plugin/blob/master/admin/helper/class-chargebee-membership-shortcodes.php

For `cb_content_show` the shortcode format is currently:

```
[cb_content_show level="1"] This content will be shown to any users who have plan associated with Level 1 [/cb_content_show]
```

What is the best method to access this function directly? I believe it derives from the function `render_content_show_hide()` - Line 707

```
public function render_content_show_hide( $attr, $content = null, $shortcode_name = '' ) { ...
```

Ideally I'd like to access as the function for example:

```
<?php
if (cb_content_show('level') == 1) :
//do something
endif; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by accessing the `get_user_meta` values.

```
<?php    
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$key = 'chargebee_user_subscriptions';
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, true  );
print_r($all_meta_for_user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like function `render_content_show_hide()` is a method of class. If you want access this function directly - you can create new class instance.

If your plugin code looks like:

```
class Shortcode_Builder{
    //...methods
    public function render_content_show_hide( $attr, $content = null, $shortcode_name = '' ) { 
        //...
    }

    //...other methods.


}
```

Create new instance

```
$builder = new Shortcode_Builder();
```

And access to your function `$builder->render_content_show_hide()`

Comment: To prevent the theme from breaking in case the plugin is not active, don't forget to wrap this in a conditional `if ( class_exists ( 'Shortcode_Builder' ) ) :`

Comment: Thanks for that. I managed to access the data by using `get_user_meta` instead... much easier :)